# Demasiado tiempo en la ejecucion

Tags: sql, sql-server

alguien me puede ayudar, pasa que tengo un informe, el cual se demora a la hora de ejecutarse, ya intente optimizarlo, pero no ha dado resultado, agradeceria si me pudieran apoyar con esto muchas gracias

```
SELECT
      FA0.Codigo,
      (LEFT (RTRIM (FA0.nombre )+' '+ RTRIM(FA0.Nombre1) +' '+RTRIM( FA0.Apellido),20) +' '+RTRIM(FA0.Apellido1)) AS NombreCliente,
      FA0.Consecutivo as Factura,
      FA0.Fecha,
      FA0.Fechavence,
      FA0.codtipodcto,
      FA0.Totalgeneral as ValorFactura,
      (
         FA0.Totalgeneral - ((IsNull(AB0.Valor, 0) + IsNull(AB0.Retencion, 0)))
      )
      as SaldoFactura
   FROM
      (
         SELECT
            S0.Nombre,
            S0.Nombre1,
            S0.Apellido,
            S0.Apellido1,
            S0.Telefono1,
            S0.EsCliente,
            S0.EsEmpleado,
            F0.tiporeferencia,
            F0.Codigo,
            F0.consecutivo,
            F0.Referencia,
            F0.Fecha,
            F0.Fechavence,
            F0.codtipodcto,
            F0.Totalgeneral 
         FROM
            tblencfacturas F0 
            INNER JOIN
               tblsocio_negocios S0 
               ON F0.codigo = S0.codigo 
         WHERE
            (YEAR(F0.fecha)=@Year) AND (MONTH(F0.fecha)=@Month)     
      )
      AS FA0
      LEFT JOIN
         (
            SELECT
               A1.codtipodcto,
               A0.Codigo,
               A1.Factura,
               SUM(A1.Valor)AS Valor,
               SUM(A1.Retencion)AS Retencion 
            FROM
               tblencabonosfactura A0 
               INNER JOIN
                  tblmvtoabonosfactura A1 
                  ON A0.documento = A1.documento 
            WHERE
                 (YEAR(A0.fecha)=@Year) AND (MONTH(A0.fecha)=@Month)        
            GROUP BY
               A1.codtipodcto,
               A0.Codigo,
               A1.Factura
         )
         AB0 
         ON FA0.consecutivo = AB0.factura 
         AND FA0.codtipodcto = AB0.codtipodcto
         WHERE FA0.Totalgeneral - ((IsNull(AB0.Valor, 0) + IsNull(AB0.Retencion, 0))) > 1 or FA0.Totalgeneral - ((IsNull(AB0.Valor, 0) + IsNull(AB0.Retencion, 0))) < -1
```

Comment: Para mejores resultados, incluye en tu pregunta la definición de las tablas. Con eso, quienes intenten ayudar podrán ver cómo están indexadas las tablas.

Comment: Tal como dice @Alfabravo, lo mejor sería que postearas la estructura de las tablas y los índices que tienen. Sin embargo, una mejora inmediata es no usar `(YEAR(X.fecha) = @Year)  AND (MONTH(X.fecha) = @Month)` y cambiarlo por una condición que **no use una función sobre la columna fecha** (porque en caso que tenga un índice, esa condición no lo puede usar). Deberías cambiarlo por algo similar a `X.Fecha >= DATEFROMPARTS(@Year,@Month,1) AND X.Fecha < DATEADD(MONTH,1,DATEFROMPARTS(@Year,@Month,1))` (o similar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Publico respuesta ya que no puedo comentar =(....

Como dice Lamak en los comentarios, trata de evitar las comparaciones con fechas, en caso de que no puedas no uses funciones de conversion en el where como (YEAR, MONT). Mejor la comparación de fechas directas, aqui difiero un poco de Lamak, en lugar de sacar la fecha en el where con DATEFROMPARTS mejor declara las variables antes del query para que sean un simple dato ya calculado y no estarlo calculando cada row. Por ejemplo:

```
DECLARE
@FechaInicio = DATEFROMPARTS(@Year,@Month,1),
@FechaFin = DATEADD(MONTH,1,@FechaInicio);

.... WHERE X.Fecha BETWEEN @FechaInicio AND @FechaFin
```

Es muy costoso hacer calculos con fechas en la misma consulta.

Otra cosa que te podria funcionar es crear tablas temporales para selects anidados que tienes. Por ejemplo:

```
-- TABLA TEMPORAL
SELECT
  S0.Nombre,
  S0.Nombre1,
  S0.Apellido,
  S0.Apellido1,
  S0.Telefono1,
  S0.EsCliente,
  S0.EsEmpleado,
  F0.tiporeferencia,
  F0.Codigo,
  F0.consecutivo,
  F0.Referencia,
  F0.Fecha,
  F0.Fechavence,
  F0.codtipodcto,
  F0.Totalgeneral
INTO #tmp1
FROM tblencfacturas F0 
INNER JOIN tblsocio_negocios S0 ON F0.codigo = S0.codigo 
WHERE F0.fecha BETWEEN @FechaInicio AND @FechaFin

-- SELECT FINAL
SELECT
  FA0.Codigo,
  (LEFT (RTRIM (FA0.nombre )+' '+ RTRIM(FA0.Nombre1) +' '+RTRIM( FA0.Apellido),20) +' '+RTRIM(FA0.Apellido1)) AS NombreCliente,
  FA0.Consecutivo as Factura,
  FA0.Fecha,
  FA0.Fechavence,
  FA0.codtipodcto,
  FA0.Totalgeneral as ValorFactura,
  ( FA0.Totalgeneral - ((IsNull(AB0.Valor, 0) + IsNull(AB0.Retencion, 0))) ) as SaldoFactura
FROM #tmp1.... (Lo que falta)

DROP TABLE #tmp1
```

Trata de todos los select anidados meterlos en tablas temporales, es mas limpio, mas facil de manipular y para sorpresa, mas eficiente.